# How to refresh netsh wlan show interface (while doing a wifi survey of the room)?

Tags: windows, wifi, netsh

I like using the command `netsh wlan show interface` to quickly get info on my wifi connection.

Does anyone know how I could have the output refresh every second? This would allow me to do a quick wifi survey of any room without having to manually enter the command every time I move.

Comment: You might benefit more from specific wifi scanner / spectrum analyser ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch file with a simple loop might do the trick:

```
@echo off
REM This is an infinite loop - you must press Ctl + C to break out
:REFRESH
Cls
netsh wlan show interface
Ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 -w 1000>nul
GOTO REFRESH
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic one-liner that you can use in PowerShell to do this. Replace the main command as needed per your OS and available commandlets. Just hit `Control-C`to stop it from running.

`do {$a=2;Get-NetAdapter | Get-NetIPAddress;Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;cls} until($a -le 1)`

Comment: Get-NetAdapter and Get-NetIPAddress requires Windows 8 or above, by the way, and the OP did not specify their OS.

Comment: Correct, that's why I stated to replace the main command as needed.  I edited my post to be more clear.  Thanks.